# Adding a photo on top corner of a two column CV template

Tags: floats, xetex

How can I add a photo on the top right/left corners to this  CV Template ?

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv

I tried to use variants of the following code to insert the photo on right top corner after moving the name to the left side:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=5cm]{photo.jpg}
\end{flushright}
\end{figure}
```

I have two problems: 
1- The photo is always at the center
2- The rest of the template (in a minipage environment) moves to a new page

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you linked to is not well set up for using as an example here, but the following works.  (Note: I did not have the fonts in used in the linked file; but I assume you do.)

Rather than post the whole thing, which is very verbose, I'll point you to where to add or subtract or move things.

[1] Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble.  (I put it just after `xcolor`.)

[2] Move the 'TITLE' section inside the first `minipage`, following the `\vspace{0pt}` line; note that the example is missing a closing brace.  I would do something like:

```
\par{\centering{\sffamily\Huge John Smith}\\ % Your name
 {\color{headings}Curriculum Vit\ae}\par
} % <--- ADDED !
```

[3] Following the second `\vspace{0pt}`, add the following lines (but you can use the fonts the file has if they are on your system):

```
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=5cm]{photo.jpg}
\end{flushright}
```

[4] Now the second minipage is too long: you need to remove some material from the example file.  For instance, if you comment out the 'Communication Skills' seciton, you'll see everything fits on one page.  That means you'll need to move things around between the left and right minipages until everything fits; you may need to pare down how verbose you are in various sections.

Comment: Thanks Jon! It works very well, but I get an empty page at the beginning.

Comment: @Tarek -- That's because one of the minipages is too long (in TeX's opinion): try removing a little at a time and see how much is too much for everything to fit on a page.  Note that it could be too long in either or both of the minipage environments since we've added material to both of them.  See which one is longer in the 2-page document, and try removing material from that one first; but you may need to remove stuff from both.

Comment: I can't use this template with TexStudio. I tried TeLaTex and LulaTeX but didn't work. Can you hlep me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @SameirDeif -- Can you be more specific?  'didn't work' can mean a lot of things; what error message(s) are you getting?  Are you using exactly the file linked to above?  (Also: 'TeXLaTex' and 'LulaTeX' are not commands you can use.  Did you in fact try with `xelatex` and `lualatex`?)

Comment: Picture of the result would be great. I find this answer helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225161/13173

Comment: @jon Where do we find the mentioned minipage? Could you add a compilable example? And help to solve the same new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400562/124842).

Comment: @Bobyandbob -- I think your question has (by now) been answered..?

Comment: @jon . No.  I can't see any minipage yet?

Comment: @Bobyandbob -- Well, I don't use templates so I don't have a historical version of the file the OP put in the question, but my guess/memory is that an older version of this template used `minipage`s, though it seems like it now does not. (Here's yet another reason for questions to include actual code in the form of an MWE.) Since the newer version of the template -- as of the date of this comment, anyway -- does not seem to use `minipage`s, there is no reason to do so now. Hopefully the newer versions of the template are constructed better than they were in 2013....