# Add image to Two-column CV on sharelatex.com

Tags: cv, sharelatex

I would like to use the following template for my CV: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv

Unfortunately the standard template does not support to include a picture. As this is common in Germany, I would like to add one. Who can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: My question is similar to the following post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101275/adding-a-photo-on-top-corner-of-a-two-column-cv-template
But the explanation was not precise enough for me to draw any conclusions. Thanks for further help...

Comment: Please do a complete example of your code (without real content) and post it here. Do a screenshot and mark the place where you want to have the image. Like this, it is just guessing.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for that hint. Found the solution by myself. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. I deleted the `\part{}` command after `\begin{document}` and pasted the following instead:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{picture.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment
\sffamily\Huge <FIRST NAME><LAST NAME>% Your name
\vspace{30pt}
\small Place of birth: <DATE>\\
\small Date of birth: <CITY>
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

before the first section. Don't forget to load `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble.