# Add profile picture in awesome CV

Tags: templates, fontawesome

I'm using this nice [CV template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) and my only problem is to insert a picture in the upper right corner of the sheet. Anyone can help me?. I have tried to use minipage but it does not work. Thanks a lot.

You can find the code [here](http://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv).

Here is my desired result:

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide Minimal Working Example (MWE), a small self contained document, which can be compiled and which show your problem. Since here are a lot of similar questions, search SE if some one has answer for a similar problem, for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225142/trouble-inserting-picture-in-cv-template?rq=1.

Comment: Well, desired result is nice, but what you try so far? Make our help more easy and please, provide  MWE as I already ask you. In this you can help with link which I give you in previous comment. Bear mind that SE is not a service do-it-for-me.

Comment: So does that mean the name-and-details block gets shrunk to fit the picture within the text margins? How wide must the picture be? Can it overhang the text margins?

Comment: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the beautiful way to obtain your expected result is to modify the template. Here i provide you a *ugly* (in term of LaTeX behavior) solution to make it easy

```
% Print the header with above personal informations
\makecvheader
\begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(460,50){\includegraphics[width=5em]{your_picture.jpeg}}
\end{picture}
```

This solution need to be avoided if it is possible but it works well for you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option to modify and add your profile picture is to use the `\photo[]{}` flag. Replace the code in your local `awesome-cv.cls` with the code in:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/master/awesome-cv.cls

There you will find the `\photo[]{}` flag:

```
\photo[circle|rectangle,edge|noedge,left|right]{"path-to-image"}
```

[]: modify options

{}: path to image