# How to add a photo in awesome CV template?

Tags: templates, awesome-cv

I want to add a photo in the awesome CV template borrowed from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm). As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387512), I tried the following:

1. Replaced the default `awesome-cv.cls` file that comes with the template, with [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/master/awesome-cv.cls).
2. Specified the path to the photo in the line: `\newcommand{\photo}[2][circle,edge,left]{<resume/photo.jpg>`

I am not able to see a photo in the pdf. Hence, I think that I am not specifying the path to the photo at the correct place. I am not able to figure out where in the 'updated' `awesome-cv.cls` file should I specify the path. I am using XeLaTeX. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of this template has already included the option for inserting the photo. All one needs to do is to uncomment the following line in `resume.tex`:

```
\photo[rectangle,noedge,right]{example-image-a}
```

and replace `example-image-a` with the image you want to insert.

Answer (score 1):

can you post a MWE of your code? Its not exactly clear to me whats the problem.
The provided template only defines the function `\photo`.
To use the command `\photo` (with the file `testphoto.jpg` in the same folder) you have to write sth. like this:

> \photo[circle, edge, left]{testphoto.jpg}

I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Can you provide more information? Which machine do you use (xelatex, lualatex, pdflatex)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question:

**Did you edit the `.cls` file** to achieve bullet point 2?

If so, **don't do that**.

You should not edit the class file. (If you've already edited it, replace it with a stock copy.)

You should instead issue, within your own LaTeX source file, the command

`\photo[circle,edge,left]{resume/photo.jpg}`