# How to upload the picture at the left side of this cv template?

Tags: graphics, positioning, cv, awesome-cv

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

% Colors for text - uncomment and modify
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

\headersocialsep[\quad\textbar\quad] % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 404-180, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843}

\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}
%\skype{skypeid}
%\stackoverflow{SOid}{SOname}
%\twitter{@twit}

\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert} % Your expertise/fields
\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."} % A quote or statement

\makecvfooter{\today}{Claud D. Park~~~Â·~~~RÃ©sumÃ©}{\thepage} % Specify the letter footer with 3 arguments: (<left>, <center>, <right>), leave any of these blank if they are not needed

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{cv-sections/education.tex}
\input{cv-sections/skills.tex}
\input{cv-sections/experience.tex}
\input{cv-sections/extracurricular.tex}
\input{cv-sections/honors.tex}
\input{cv-sections/presentation.tex}
\input{cv-sections/writing.tex}
\input{cv-sections/committees.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which picture? Upload to what?

Comment: Passport size picture at left side on the top with name

Answer (score 2):

The following patch updated `\makecvheader` to insert an image to the left of the name. It's set using a `l`eft over`lap` so as to maintain the regular layout.

Add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}% <cmd>
  {\headerfirstnamestyle}% <search>
  {\leavevmode% Start paragraph
   \llap{% Left overLAP
   \includegraphics[height=29pt]{example-image-9x16}\qquad}% Passport image + space
   \headerfirstnamestyle}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

just before `\begin{document}`.

[image]

---

[References](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV#quick-start):

- [Edit Résumé on OverLeaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/tvmzpvdjfqxp)
- [Edit Résumé on ShareLaTeX.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv)
- [Edit Cover Letter on OverLeaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv-cover-letter/pfzzjspkthbk)
- [Edit Cover Letter on ShareLaTeX.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/awesome-cv-cover-letter)

Comment: Maybe related http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225161/13173 - - Why not `smash` approach?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Sure, assuming you don't have an oversized image that then may overlap over the (top) page margin.

Comment: How to make all the head sections (e.g., Education) all red instead of highlighting just the first three letters?

Comment: @Thiago: Add somewhere in your preamble: `\makeatletter \def\@sectioncolor{\ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{\color{awesome}}{}} \makeatother`