# How can I add a picture to CV template?

Tags: floats, xetex, templates, cv

I'm writing my CV on xelatex using the template
Freeman Curriculum Vitae on https://www.latextemplates.com/template/freeman-cv
I would like to add my face, `face.jpg`, to my CV above the caption Doctoral Reseach. What modifications I need to do for the template?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Did you search the side for e.g. "picture CV template" and studied the results?

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225142/trouble-inserting-picture-in-cv-template)

Answer (score 2):

In the template you have linked to:

Put `face.jpg` in your project folder.

Put the following code after `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` and before `\begin{document}` (this area is called the Preamble):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Add the following code before `\section{Doctoral Research}`:

```
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{face.jpg}
\end{centering}
```