# How do I place a custom image logo next to my name on resume?

Tags: graphics, formatting, pdftex, header-footer, includegraphics

I cloned and am using a developer's resume style (by [Cies](https://github.com/cies/resume)) written in LaTeX for my own purposes which I'd found on GitHub but I am unsuccessfully trying to make three changes:

1. Add "SOME_TEXT" above the name like a header (tried to make a header with `\fancy` but they don't show)
2. Move the `Last update on \today` to the far right of "SOME_TEXT" in (1)
3. <strike>In the space used by `Last update on \today`, place a Professional Society emblem instead, i.e. `\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{society-logo.jpg}`</strike>

The idea behind (1) is that "SOME_TEXT" will be written "Private". Currently, I am achieving this through a scaled and positioned watermark (because I also want the grey color):

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\textsc{PRIVATE}}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.07}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkVerCenter{1cm}
\SetWatermarkHorCenter{3.3cm}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.6}
```

As for (2), this part of the code is controlled by the style defined in [resume.sty](https://github.com/cies/resume/blob/master/resume.sty) line 117:

```
% main title (name) with subtitle (date)
\newcommand\maintitle[3]{\vbox to 0pt{\hfill\scriptsize\color{gray} #3}\vspace{-0.4em}\noindent{\LARGE \textbf{#1}}\ \ \ \emph{#2}}
```

And I don't know how to change that.

<strike>As for (3) what I am currently doing is adding a `\\` after my name of the main resume tex file, i.e. [line 32](https://github.com/cies/resume/blob/master/cies-breijs-resume.tex), and bringing in my society emblem as an included graphic, i.e.:</strike>

```
\maintitle{Joanna Smith}{\space}{Last update on \today.}\\
...
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{society-logo.jpg}`
```

However, this causes LaTeX to push the text following it further down the page which is not what I want. I can semi-solve the positioning with `\hfill` before the `\includegraphics` but this doesn't solve bringing the text back to directly below my name (which would be to the left of the graphic). I should not even use the `\\` at all but if I don't the `\maintitle` customer command breaks.

Again, I want the graphic/emblem/image in place of the `\Last update on \today` while the `Last update on \today` is moved to the far right of the watermark "PRIVATE" but it's possible a watermark is not the right solution either.

I've tried using `\raisebox`, float figure, but not luck. I simply don't understand how to do it. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:

I found a solution to (3) here: [Trouble inserting picture in CV template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225142/trouble-inserting-picture-in-cv-template)

However, I am still looking to solve (1) and (2).

EDIT#2:

Here's the code for my resume:

```
% LaTeX source of my resume
% =========================

% Commented for easy reuse... ;)

% See the `README.md` file for more info.

% This file is licensed under the CC-NC-ND Creative Commons license.

% Start a document with the here given default font size and paper size.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Set the page margins.
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.75in,headheight=20pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.75in,headheight=20pt]{geometry}

% Setup the language.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{Some-long-word}

% Makes resume-specific commands available.
\usepackage{/home/joanna/resume/resume}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{{/home/joanna/society_reg/}}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\textsc{PRIVATE USE ONLY}}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.07}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkVerCenter{1cm}
\SetWatermarkHorCenter{3.3cm}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.6}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}  % begin the content of the document
\sloppy  % this to relax whitespacing in favour of straight margins

% title on top of the document
\maintitle{Joanna Smith, GVM.}{\space}{Last update on \today.}

\nobreakvspace{0.3em}  % add some page break averse vertical spacing

% \noindent prevents paragraph's first lines from indenting
% \mbox is used to obfuscate the email address
% \sbull is a spaced bullet
% \href well..
% \\ breaks the line into a new paragraph
\noindent\href{mailto:joanna@myemail.test}{joanna\mbox{}@\mbox{}myemail.test}
\sbull\textsmaller{+}1 (0)112233445566\hfill
\raisebox{-.45\totalheight}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{reg-logo.jpg}}
%$\smash{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{reg-logo.jpg}}$
%\sbull
%\href{https://github.com/cies}{github.com/cies}\sbull
%\href{http://linkedin.com/in/ciesbreijs}{linkedin.com/in/ciesbreijs}
\\
Test City, Globe.

\spacedhrule{0.9em}{-0.4em}  % a horizontal line with some vertical spacing before and after

\roottitle{Profile}  % a root section title

\vspace{-1.3em}  % some vertical spacing
\begin{multicols}{2}  % open a multicolumn environment
\noindent \emph{Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum.}
\end{multicols}


\spacedhrule{0em}{-0.4em}

\roottitle{Experience}

...

\end{document}
```

Note: this code will just generate the topmost fifth of the resume. I've not included the rest of my code because the rest of my code isn't where I'm having the issue, but where the '...' are before `\end{document}` you can paste in the original developer's code there to emulate what I see ( the `resume.sty` file from the Dev's git repo).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you make your example compilable? No need to put your whole CV here, but it will be helpful if you add a complete example beginning with ``\documentclass{...}`` and ending with ``\end{document}``.

Comment: @Vincent Sure, I will be a few minutes...

Comment: @Vincent I've updated as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work by adding a header with `fancyhdr`. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.75in,headheight=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{Some-long-word}

\usepackage{resume}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%\graphicspath{{/home/joanna/society_reg/}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[L]{\textcolor{black!40}{\textsc{PRIVATE USE ONLY}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textcolor{black!40}{\small Last update on \today.}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}  % begin the content of the document
\sloppy  % this to relax whitespacing in favour of straight margins

\maintitle{Joanna Smith, GVM.}{}{}

\nobreakvspace{0.3em}  % add some page break averse vertical spacing

\noindent\href{mailto:joanna@myemail.test}{joanna\mbox{}@\mbox{}myemail.test}
\sbull\textsmaller{+}1 (0)112233445566\hfill
\raisebox{-.45\totalheight}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
\\
Test City, Globe.

\spacedhrule{0.9em}{-0.4em}  % a horizontal line with some vertical spacing before and after

\roottitle{Profile}  % a root section title

\vspace{-1.3em}  % some vertical spacing
\begin{multicols}{2}  % open a multicolumn environment
\noindent \emph{Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum.}
\end{multicols}

\spacedhrule{0em}{-0.4em}

\roottitle{Experience}

...

\end{document}
```

Note that I changed the line

```
\usepackage{/home/joanna/resume/resume}
```

to simply

```
\usepackage{resume}
```

(This is to put the file `resmue.sty` in the same folder as this `.tex` file.)