# Add photo to a two columns CV template

Tags: floats, positioning

How can I add a photo on the right top corner of this cv template ?

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv

If it is possible I would like to lower a little bit the second column so I could put an image like this :

[image]

Here is the full code of the template :

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\part{John Doe}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

Software development for the industrial automation sector: configuration
front-end in C with interface based on \href{http://www.gtk.org/}{GTK+},
web applications and sites on LAMP platforms grounded on the
\href{http://www.silverstripe.org/}{SilverStripe} framework,
supervisor programs in LabVIEW and remote system in
\href{http://www.lua.org/}{Lua} on GNU/Linux systems.

\item{January 2002 -- June 2004}
     {TEMA s.r.l., Travagliato}
     {PLC Omron development}

Development and testing of automatic and semiautomatic machines for
ribbon winding on spools and rolls (safety belts, hook-and-loop tapes,
elastic ribbon and bindings). Designing of electrical schematics on
2D cad and user manuals drafting.

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.

\item{September 1996 -- September 1998}
     {Elettronica EFFE-GI s.n.c., Cazzago}
     {PC and PLC Hitachi development}

Development of automatic machines in general, here included the design
of electrical, pneumatic and hydraulic schematics on 2D cad and the PLC
programming. Implementation of configuration and logging front-end using
RS232 serial communications between PC and PLC-based transfer machines
in BASIC, Pascal and C.

\end{eventlist}

\personal
    [www.entidi.com]
    {viale Conciliazione, \newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
    {+39 (30) 0000000}
    {ntd@entidi.it}

\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{yearlist}



\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Italian}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Oral: fair -- Written: good}
\item{Spanish}{Oral: good}
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {C, PHP, HTML, CSS, autotools, git, gcc, GTK+, GObject, shell,
      MS-DOS, Linux, ladder, G-Code}

\item{Intermediate}
     {Lua, \LaTeX, MySQL, VBA, cuBasic, pascal, subversion, LabVIEW}

\item{Basic level}
     {Windows, FreeBSD, OpenIndiana, Postgres}

\end{factlist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I can compile the file, I just need to add a photo to it. Make sure you have downloaded the following class before running the code : http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/source/file/master/tccv.cls

Comment: Add the code you tried to **your question** and please do not force people here to visit other web pages ...

Comment: Related to [Adding a photo on top corner of a two column CV template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101275/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob I've already seen that question but the answer provided doesn't match with the code that I provided. In his second point, he mentioned a 'minipage' but there isn't any..

Comment: I see, maybe @jon could help. I added a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use package `textpos` (get more informations with `texdoc textpos`) like in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{tccv}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % <======================================


\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{4}(12.5,0.5) % {〈hsize〉}(〈hpos〉,〈vpos〉) <==============
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\end{textblock} % <=====================================================

\part{John Doe}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

Software development for the industrial automation sector: configuration
front-end in C with interface based on \href{http://www.gtk.org/}{GTK+},
web applications and sites on LAMP platforms grounded on the
\href{http://www.silverstripe.org/}{SilverStripe} framework,
supervisor programs in LabVIEW and remote system in
\href{http://www.lua.org/}{Lua} on GNU/Linux systems.

\item{January 2002 -- June 2004}
     {TEMA s.r.l., Travagliato}
     {PLC Omron development}

Development and testing of automatic and semiautomatic machines for
ribbon winding on spools and rolls (safety belts, hook-and-loop tapes,
elastic ribbon and bindings). Designing of electrical schematics on
2D cad and user manuals drafting.

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.

\item{September 1996 -- September 1998}
     {Elettronica EFFE-GI s.n.c., Cazzago}
     {PC and PLC Hitachi development}

Development of automatic machines in general, here included the design
of electrical, pneumatic and hydraulic schematics on 2D cad and the PLC
programming. Implementation of configuration and logging front-end using
RS232 serial communications between PC and PLC-based transfer machines
in BASIC, Pascal and C.

\end{eventlist}

\personal
    [www.entidi.com]
    {viale Conciliazione, \newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
    {+39 (30) 0000000}
    {ntd@entidi.it}

\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{yearlist}



\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Italian}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Oral: fair -- Written: good}
\item{Spanish}{Oral: good}
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {C, PHP, HTML, CSS, autotools, git, gcc, GTK+, GObject, shell,
      MS-DOS, Linux, ladder, G-Code}

\item{Intermediate}
     {Lua, \LaTeX, MySQL, VBA, cuBasic, pascal, subversion, LabVIEW}

\item{Basic level}
     {Windows, FreeBSD, OpenIndiana, Postgres}

\end{factlist}
\end{document}
```

Play with the vallues of `begin{textblock}{4}(12.5,0.5)` for your needs, depending on your image ...

My example gives the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

If your image is larger, for example 10*16, you have to add  the following code **before** `\personal`:

```
\newpage  % <===========================================================
\parbox[c][3cm]{\textwidth}{} % <=======================================
```

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass{tccv}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % <======================================


\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{4}(12.5,0.5) % {〈hsize〉}(〈hpos〉,〈vpos〉) <==============
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-10x16}
\end{textblock} % <=====================================================

\part{John Doe}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

Software development for the industrial automation sector: configuration
front-end in C with interface based on \href{http://www.gtk.org/}{GTK+},
web applications and sites on LAMP platforms grounded on the
\href{http://www.silverstripe.org/}{SilverStripe} framework,
supervisor programs in LabVIEW and remote system in
\href{http://www.lua.org/}{Lua} on GNU/Linux systems.

\item{January 2002 -- June 2004}
     {TEMA s.r.l., Travagliato}
     {PLC Omron development}

Development and testing of automatic and semiautomatic machines for
ribbon winding on spools and rolls (safety belts, hook-and-loop tapes,
elastic ribbon and bindings). Designing of electrical schematics on
2D cad and user manuals drafting.

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.

\item{September 1996 -- September 1998}
     {Elettronica EFFE-GI s.n.c., Cazzago}
     {PC and PLC Hitachi development}

Development of automatic machines in general, here included the design
of electrical, pneumatic and hydraulic schematics on 2D cad and the PLC
programming. Implementation of configuration and logging front-end using
RS232 serial communications between PC and PLC-based transfer machines
in BASIC, Pascal and C.

\end{eventlist}

\newpage  % <===========================================================
\parbox[c][3cm]{\textwidth}{} % <=======================================
\personal
    [www.entidi.com]
    {viale Conciliazione, \newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
    {+39 (30) 0000000}
    {ntd@entidi.it}


\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{yearlist}


\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Italian}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Oral: fair -- Written: good}
\item{Spanish}{Oral: good}
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {C, PHP, HTML, CSS, autotools, git, gcc, GTK+, GObject, shell,
      MS-DOS, Linux, ladder, G-Code}

\item{Intermediate}
     {Lua, \LaTeX, MySQL, VBA, cuBasic, pascal, subversion, LabVIEW}

\item{Basic level}
     {Windows, FreeBSD, OpenIndiana, Postgres}

\end{factlist}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But my photo is a little larger so the yellow box steps on it. Do you have a tip to lower slightly the second column? I tried adding `\fbox{\parbox[c][2cm]{\textwidth}{}} right before the \personal statement but it leaves an empty box with black borders.

Comment: how about just adding a \vspace{3cm} before \includegraphics?